# Does using Integer.MAX_VALUE in the for statement prevent repetition from stopping?

Tags: java

```
long iter_cnt = 0;
    for (int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        iter_cnt = iter_cnt + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(iter_cnt);
```

I compiled this code and it keeps repeating without stopping. What's wrong with this?

Comment: replace your `for-loop` with `long iter_cnt = 1`;

Comment: Hint: every `int`-value is smaller or equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`...

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` is resetting `i` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
        System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

Given below is the explanation from [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order
> bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large
> two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the
> result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two
> operand values.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is when `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is added with 1, it sets the minimum value of integer `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. As we are specifying the datatype as Integer, it can hold maximum upto it's range. When we try to make that value exceeds it's limit, it tends to point the min value of it's datatype. It is same for whatever datatype we specify